# Vue: how to if load resource ( initiator,assets ) return console.log("all resource done ")

Tags: vue.js, electron

how to if load resource ( initiator,assets ) return console.log("all resource done ")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR1UK.png)

Comment: Please clarify your question. I can only very barely understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could register a callback on the 'load' event. It fires as soon as all page resources have been loaded.
This is a great explanation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event